# Convert objects in my arraylist to string arrays in android

Tags: android, xml, string, object, arraylist

I am using a XML parser and as result I get a `ArrayList` with my objects:

```
ArrayList <Datapoint> itemsList = parseXML();
```

One Datapoint object consists of the following Strings:

```
name: a
stateBased: b
mainNumber: c
dptID: d
groupadress: e
priority: f
```

I was already able to display all the objects with this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++)
{
    item = itemsList.get(i);
    parsedData = parsedData + "----->\n";
    String name = parsedData + "Name: " + item.getName() + "\n";
    String stateBased = parsedData + "stateBased: " + item.getStateBased() + "\n";
    String mainNumber = parsedData + "mainNumber: " + item.getMainNumber() + "\n";
    String dptID = parsedData + "dptID: "+ item.getDptID() + "\n";
    String groupadress = parsedData + "Groupadress: "+ item.getGroupadress() + "\n";
    String priority = parsedData + "priority: "+ item.getPriority() + "\n";
}
```

It would be great to have for example 5 string arrays each as a object from my ArrayList including the strings shown above.

```
String [] Object 1 = {name = a, stateBased = b, dptID =c, ..}
String [] Object 2 = {name = d, stateBased = e, dptID =f, ..}
String [] Object 3 = {name = g, stateBased = h, dptID =i, ..}
```

But how can i programmatically create a StringArray with each iteration? Something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++)
{
    item = itemsList.get(i);
    String [] [i] = new String [itemsList.size()];
    //insert strings to the array
}
```

How can I realize this or what would be an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: for filtering one object, you could use Collections.binarySearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem using the following code:

```
ArrayList <Datapoint> itemsList = parseXML();
String[itemsList.size()][4] = new String();

for(int i=0;i<itemsList.size();i++)
{
     item = itemsList.get(i);      
     String [i] [0] = item.getName();
     String [i] [1] = item.getStateBased();
     String [i] [2] = item.getMainNumber();
     String [i] [3] = item.getGroupadress();
     String [i] [4] = item.getPriority();
}
```

And `private static String[][] String = null;` is defined as global variable.